# Find $k$-th derivative of $g(t)=e^{Cf(t)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics

Is there a formula for findind the $k$-th derivative of a function like $g(t)=e^{Cf(t)}$? I'm trying to deduce it and I got to the conclusion I could write something like $$g^{(k)}(t)=\sum_{k=j_1+\ldots+j_k} C_{j_1\cdots j_k} f^{(j_1)}(t)\cdots f^{(j_k)}(t),$$ where the constants $C_{j_1\cdots j_k}$ will depend on $C$. However I wasn't able to find an expression for $C_{j_1\cdots j_k}$.

Of course in the above sum I'm considering much more terms than I need for it suffices summing over the partitions of $k$ but I don't know how to write it in the sum sign. For example, if $k=4$ then it suffices considering the partitions $4$, $3+1$, $2+2$, $1+1+1+1$ so that the corresponding derivatives will be $f^{(iv)}(t), f^{'''}(t)f^{'}(t), (f^{''}(t))^2, (f^{\prime})^4$. I also have an idea about the behaviour of the coefficients that I'll illustrate with the case $k=4$.  The coefficient corresponding to the partition $3+1$ will be: $$\frac{\textrm{number of ways of distributing 1, 3 into 4 slots}}{\max\{1, 3\}=3}\times\ \textrm{power of}\ C.$$ In the numerator I mean we must count all the possible $12$ forms: $$(1, 3, 0, 0), (1, 0, 3, 0), (1, 0, 0, 3), (0, 1, 3, 0), (0, 1, 0, 3), (0, 0, 1, 3), (0, 0, 3, 1), (0, 3, 0, 1), (0, 3, 1, 0), (3, 0, 1, 0), (3, 0, 0, 1), (3, 1, 0, 0)$$ so that the coefficient will be $12/3=4\times \textrm{power of}\ C$.

To illustrate this I did some computations up to $k=4$:

\begin{align*}
\displaystyle g^{\prime}(t)&= C e^{Cf(t)} f^{\prime}(t)\\
g^{\prime\prime}(t)&=Ce^{Cf(t)}(f^{\prime\prime}(t)+C (f^\prime(t))^2)\\
g^{\prime\prime\prime}(t)&=C e^{Cf(t)} [f^{\prime\prime\prime}(t)+3 C f^{\prime}(t) f^{\prime\prime}(t)+C^2 (f^\prime(t))^3]\\
g^{(iv)}(t)&=f^{(iv)}(t)+4C f^\prime(t)f^{\prime\prime\prime}(t)+6C^2 (f^\prime(t))^2 f^{\prime\prime}(t)+3C (f^{\prime\prime}(t))^2+C^3 (f^\prime(t))^4
\end{align*}
The powers of $C$ are still a mistery for me.

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) might help you.

Comment: Perfect, that was all I needed =) Thanks

Comment: See also [Hermite polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just an algorithm to evaluate the derivatives, use Taylor arithmetics and
$$
g'(x)=C·f'(x)·g(x)
$$
so that in series coefficients 
$$
f(x+t)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kt^k+O(t^{n+1})\\
g(x+t)=\sum_{k=0}^n b_kt^k+O(t^{n+1})
$$
you get
$$
\sum_{m=0}^n mb_mt^{m-1}=C·\sum_{j=0}^n ja_jt^{j-1}·\sum_{k=0}^n b_kt^k+O(t^{n})\\
mb_m=C·\sum_{j=1}^m ja_j·b_{m-j}
$$
which allows you to successively compute the coefficients of $g$ and thus $g^{(m)}(x)=m!·b_m$ from the derivatives of $f$ using $a_k=\frac{f^{(k)}(x)}{k!}$.